# Technique for holding a horizontal minifig in place (swimmer)

Tags: building, minifigures

I'm building a scene on an 8x8 base plate, ideally the depth of the base is 1 full brick high. The design is to have a swimmer minifig horizontal (i.e. swimming) but also at an angle to the base plate, and ideally connected, not just laid on top. I can achieve the angle with a 2x2 turntable plate, and get the swimmer horizontal with a 1x2 hinge brick on top of the turntable, but this makes the swimmer quite high. Any ideas on how to achieve the same - I'm wondering if a torso attachment on the hidden underside of the minifig might work but can't think what piece to use.

Comment: It seems like you got a good suggestion already. However, if you were to look for any assistance in the future it would be good to have a picture of the setup you already have shared next time.

Answer (score 3):

Mmmh... If you base doesn't have to be all solid...

Recess some piece in there in which you can insert the arm-side of a mini-fig hand.
Grasp your swimmer by the toes on one of its feet, with that hand.
That will give you a horizontal/slightly upwards position on the mini-fig and you can further increase the angle by adjusting the mini-figs leg.

Comment: Brilliant! It looks like a "modified 1x1 with clip vertical" does the same job too! - thank you!!

Comment: @Watters Didn't even think of that. That is even easier  and takes even less vertical space.

Comment: Interesting, I was experimenting with "old" Lego (clips and legs) and got the parts for my build off Bricklink and the Lego was "newer" - I had to sand the clips a little bit to get them in.

Answer (score 1):

There are several pieces which can be attached to minifigures to pose them. Recently a line of collectible minifigures introduced a transparent "[handle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=65578)" with a single stud which could be connected to the feet or legs of the minifigure

[image]

This piece can be rotated in the anti-stud to angle whichever way is convenient, then held in place using a hole or clip.

[image]